# Laravel Eloquent Relationship instead of Join on third table not related to parent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an `orders` table and an `order_items` table that are related with `hasMany` and `belongsTo` respectively.

There is also a `products` table that is related to `order_items` with `hasMany` and `belongsTo` respectively.

What my goal is, is to create an `Orders` object that also includes the products without using a `join`.

Is this is possible, how would the relationships be set up to make this happen in Eloquent?

Ideally, I would like to have it in a `with` but I cannot figure out how to make this work.

Order model:

```
class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
    }
}
```

OrderItem model:

```
class OrderItem extends Eloquent {

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
    }
}
```

Query:

```
$order = Order::with('user', 'orderItems', 'address')
        ->where('orders.id', $id)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`belongsToMany`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) relationship

```
class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product','order_items','order_id','product_id'); //Assuming that 'order_items' table has order_id and product_id as foreign keys
    }
}
```

You can also [work](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) with pivot table (`order_items` table in your case).

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it works, but it seems like `hasManyThrough` is what I wanted, but it doesn't work for this case. I had it exactly as you have `belongsToMany` here in the `Order` model, but I kept receiving a SQL error. Your suggestion does work, however still somewhat confusing why my previous code failed.

Comment: I'm confused, it works with `belongsToMany` or not? I don't think you need `hasManyThrough` relation in this case. If it doesn't work, please show your tables

Comment: Your answer definitely works. I was saying hasManyThrough seemed more intuitive. But I was incorrect.

Comment: yeah [`hasManyThrough`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through) works if you have an intermediate relation not a pivot table, also your previous code is correct, you can include the products through nested relationship: `Order::with('user', 'orderItems.product', 'address')`, but it will add one more request and you may have duplicate products (e.g. two orderItems belongs to the same product)